# Unity .Net Syntax for System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dir)

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, version

I have some code that works in my windows forms project:

```
MatBaseIndicies = new Dictionary<string, int>();
string dir = Path.Combine(Data.BaseDir, "images");
dir = Path.Combine(dir, "equipment");
var subfolders = System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories(dir);
int counter = 0;
foreach(string sub in subfolders)
{
   MatBaseIndicies.Add(Path.GetFileName(sub), counter);
   counter++;
}
```

Basically, this code reads all the subfolders and then adds their names as the key to a dictionary so that they can be looked up an int.

If you want to know the purpose of this (skip this paragraph if you don't): This is part of a highly customizable game that searches folders to find all of it's assets at start up. When objects are serialized for saving, the string value is saved so that the link is never lost to the relevant assets. When objects are de-serialized, the object only needs to store an int which looks up the string (which saves memory)

This code does not compile in Unity 5 because Unity uses a much older version of .Net which does not contain a definition for "System.IO.Directory.EnumerateDirectories"

I'm sorry, I'm not to sure about the exact .Net version numbers...

How can this Code be re-written to support Unity 5?

Comment: Try GetDirectories instead of EnumetateDirectories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity is built on .Net 3.5, which is, as you have pointed out a much older version.

You do have an option though, the [Directory.GetDirectories](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directory.getdirectories(v=vs.110).aspx) function will give you (almost) the same result.

Comment: Thanks. Easiest question ever, right? Seems so obvious now. In hind-sight, I don't know why I assumed that I didn't already have the answer at my fingertips. perhaps I can set visual studio to .Net 3.5 somehow, and then I won't have to ask.

Comment: Heh, you're right, this is possibly one of the easiest answers I've ever had. Also, not too familiar with VS for Unity (Primarily a Mono user), but isn't there an option in VS to set your solution's target to whatever framework you wish?